# iOS Cocoa - custom uipickerview or similar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, custom-controls, uipickerview

So I'm trying to create something like this for an app I'm making and I'm not exactly sure how to go about it. I was thinking of customizing UIPickerView or something with ScrollView. One of the concerns is the small size I would like it to be. I'm aiming for 85x120px size (much smaller than what I could get UIPicker to be. Any help/pointing in the right direction would be appreciated.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0HmN.png)

Also this app will be iOS 6+ so any new controls would be fine :)

Comment: As far as i Know You can't change the height of Picker View. Although Width can be altered.

Comment: i am looking for the same kind of customization

Answer (score 0):

UIPicker can change width, but can not change height directly. But there are some way around.

You can use CGAffineTransformScale() to change the height.

```
CGAffineTransform transform = pickerView.transform;
transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1, 10);
pickerView.transform = transform;
```

You can check more about CGAffineTransform, that is really helpful if you want to customize something.